# Combining duplicates into an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like below

```
[
{"st":"10:30,22:30","day":1},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":3},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":4},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":7},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":6},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":2},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":5}
]
```

I want to convert it like below

```
[
 {"st":"10:30,22:30","day":[1]},
 {"st":"9:30,20:30","day":[3,4]},
 {"st":"11:0,23:30","day":[7,6]},
 {"st":"8:0,23:0","day":[2,5]}
]
```

Based on the duplicate "st" values i want to merge those corresponding days.
i was tried so many methods but i was unable to do. can anybody please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is the following:

```js
var yourArray = [
{"st":"10:30,22:30","day":1},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":3},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":4},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":7},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":6},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":2},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":5}
];

var newArray =
Array.from(new Set(yourArray.map(elem => elem.st))) // get unique st's
    .map(elem => ({
        st: elem,
        day: yourArray.filter(el => el.st === elem).map(el => el.day) // get array of days
}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Note that this uses ES6 features and you need to use a transpiler (e.g. Babel) to use it in non-ES6 compliant browsers.

**Resources**

- [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

This basic code might could help.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.originalArray = [{
      "st": "10:30,22:30",
      "day": 1
    }, {
      "st": "9:30,20:30",
      "day": 3
    }, {
      "st": "9:30,20:30",
      "day": 4
    }, {
      "st": "11:0,23:30",
      "day": 7
    }, {
      "st": "11:0,23:30",
      "day": 6
    }, {
      "st": "8:0,23:0",
      "day": 2
    }, {
      "st": "8:0,23:0",
      "day": 5
    }];
    $scope.result = [];

    (function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.originalArray, function(value) {
        var locateIndex = _.findIndex($scope.result, {
          'st': value.st
        });
        if (locateIndex === -1) {
          var currentDayValue = value.day;
          value.day = [currentDayValue];
          $scope.result.push(value);
          return;
        }

        $scope.result[locateIndex].day.push(value.day);
      });
    }).call()
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  original array
  <div>{{ originalArray }}</div>
  <br/>result
  <div>{{ result }}</div>
</div>
```

PS: I use lodash as JS utility library. (findIndex helper function)

Comment: Perfectly working for my scenario. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Create temp array for check duplicate `st` value by `indexOf`.Check `st` value exist in temp ,if not change your day value to array type .If exist push day to previous index and after deleted by `splice`

```
var object = [
{"st":"10:30,22:30","day":1},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":3},
{"st":"9:30,20:30","day":4},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":7},
{"st":"11:0,23:30","day":6},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":2},
{"st":"8:0,23:0","day":5}
];
var temp = [];
for(var i = object.length-1;i > 0;i--){
     if(temp.indexOf(object[i].st) != -1){
          var exist = temp.indexOf(object[i].st);
          object[exist].day.push(object[i].day);
          object.splice(i,1);
     }
     else{
         temp[i] = object[i].st;
         var d = object[i].day;
         object[i].day = [];
         object[i].day.push(d);
     }
}
console.log(object);
```